# How to Bind Two Different tables in Same DataGrid Item Source using WPF EntityFrameWork

Tags: wpf

I am new for WPF.i am having two tables SalesRep and Item and i have datagrid i need to display both table columns combindly at a time in wpf datagrid. there is no relation in both tables.

```
<Grid><DataGrid Name="salesrepGrid1" ItemsSource="{Binding SalesReps}" ItemSource="{Binding Items}" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
```

Comment: First of all, ItemSource does not exist in Datagrid. Is it a custom property made by you?

Comment: Second, you have two separate ItemsCollections, and you want to use them both in the same Datagrid. I do not think that this is possible. A DataGrid can have only one ItemsSource, but the Objects can have more properties, and each public property could be displayed as a Column.

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer may not be the one you want, you need to build a data model that correctly models your data, if you do this then you no longer need multiple sources as you would have a single data model

eg

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.Resources>
        <x:Array x:Key="team" Type="local:SalesTeam">
            <local:SalesTeam>
                <local:SalesTeam.Reps>
                    <local:SalesRep Name="A" Pay="5.2" Quota="50" />
                    <local:SalesRep Name="B" Pay="5.2" Quota="50" />
                    <local:SalesRep Name="C" Pay="5.2" Quota="50" />
                </local:SalesTeam.Reps>
                <local:SalesTeam.Items>
                    <local:SalesItem Name="Rocks" Qty="50" Value="1"/>
                    <local:SalesItem Name="Paper" Qty="50" Value="1"/>
                    <local:SalesItem Name="Sissros" Qty="50" Value="1"/>
                </local:SalesTeam.Items>
            </local:SalesTeam>
            <local:SalesTeam >
                <local:SalesTeam.Reps>
                    <local:SalesRep Name="1" Pay="5.2" Quota="50" />
                    <local:SalesRep Name="2" Pay="5.2" Quota="50" />
                    <local:SalesRep Name="3" Pay="5.2" Quota="50" />
                </local:SalesTeam.Reps>
                <local:SalesTeam.Items>
                    <local:SalesItem Name="Row" Qty="50" Value="1"/>
                    <local:SalesItem Name="Sham" Qty="50" Value="1"/>
                    <local:SalesItem Name="Bow" Qty="50" Value="1"/>
                </local:SalesTeam.Items>
            </local:SalesTeam>
        </x:Array>
    </Window.Resources>
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Mode=OneWay, Source={StaticResource team}}" >
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TabControl>
                    <TabItem Header="Reps">
                        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Reps}" />
                    </TabItem>
                    <TabItem Header="Items">
                        <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"/>
                    </TabItem>
                </TabControl>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</Window>
```

Model:

```
public class SalesTeam 
{
    //details on team
    public ObservableCollection<SalesRep> Reps { get; } = new ObservableCollection<SalesRep>();

    public ObservableCollection<SalesItem> Items { get; } = new ObservableCollection<SalesItem>();
}


public class SalesRep : INotifyPropertyChanged
{

    private string name;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set
        {
            name = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Name)));
        }
    }


    private int quota;

    public int Quota
    {
        get { return quota; }
        set
        {
            quota = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Quota)));
        }
    }
    private double pay;

    public double Pay
    {
        get { return pay; }
        set
        {
            pay = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Pay)));
        }
    }
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}

public class SalesItem : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string name;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return name; }
        set
        {
            name = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Name)));
        }
    }


    private int qty;

    public int Qty
    {
        get { return qty; }
        set
        {
            qty = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Qty)));
        }
    }
    private double val;

    public double Value
    {
        get { return val; }
        set
        {
            val = value;
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(nameof(Value)));
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}
```

In this example i've build the View Model in the XAML but you could source it from anywhere and here i'm just using an array of teams to populate the Items control and templating a Tab control for each data grid